# Draw A Rectangle With Asterisks

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a C++ Program to display a rectangle drawn in asterisks. I have the program running properly except for the fact that only one side of the heights of my rectangles print. Here is the code I have currently written for the display rectangle method.

```
void Rectangle::displayRectangle()
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < height - 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `width` or `height` defined

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you tell us what you think each of four for() loop is going to do?

Comment: An example of the current output would be useful, as would some comments in the code explaining the intent of each section.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<height-2; i++)` this loop should do more than just write an asterisks.

Comment: The code above doesn't even compile, the brackets arent balanced - there are 5 `{`'s and 6 `}`'s

Comment: fairly easy to solve this. Specify a width and height.  When drawing the width print an asterisk for each length of width. When drawing height print an asterisk followed by width-1 spaces and another asterisks, loop height times to print this. Finally print another row of width.

Comment: @dwcanillas I must have added an extra } on accident when I was transferring the code, it compiles in my program.

Comment: @Wimmel what else should it do?

Comment: @hannah you should remove the extra `}`, then

Comment: @Alex how would I write the code for that?

Comment: @hannah can you please show us how you are defining `width` and height`, what the expected result is, and what it is actually displaying?

Comment: I just told you :).  If you're confused about printing the height build a string that will look like `*                *` for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a width and height at the start then you only need 3 loops. The first will print the top line of the rectangle. The second will print both sides of the rectangle (minus the very top and very bottom of the sides). The third will print the bottom line of the rectangle.

Like so

```
// Width and height must both be at least 2
unsigned int width = 7;  // Example value
unsigned int height = 5; // Example value
// Print top row
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < width; i++);
{
    std::cout << "*";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
// Print sides
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < height - 2; i++)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(width - 1) << std::left << "*";
    std::cout << "*" << std::endl;
}
// Print bottom row
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    std::cout << "*";
}
std::endl;
```

You will need to include both `iostream` and `iomanip` for this to work (`setw` is part of `iomanip`).

The top and bottom rows could also be done using the method to fill spaces with a given character, but I cannot recall that method right now.

Comment: thank you so so so much! I am an extreme beginner and this was exactly what I needed to fix my code. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This can be done much easier and clearer.
The logic here is to draw from line to line, so you only need one loop
 (I chose to use the auto specifier in this example because I think it looks neater and used often in modern c++, if your compiler doesn't support c++11, use char, int etc.):

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto star      = '*';
    auto space     = ' ';
    auto width     = 20;
    auto height    = 5;
    auto space_cnt = width-2;

    for (int i{0}; i != height+1; ++i) {
        // if 'i' is the first line or the last line, print stars all the way.
        if (i == 0 || i == height)
            cout << string(width, star) << endl;
        else // print [star, space, star]
            cout << star << string(space_cnt, space) << star << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `auto space = ' '`? seriously?

Comment: Seems like unnecessary generality at the expense of additional typing and thinking for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't see the second vertical line, because you don't draw it in your line loop.

```
void DrawRect(int w, int h, char c)
{
    cout << string(w, c) << '\n';
    for (int y = 1; y < h - 1; ++y)
        cout << c << string(w - 2, ' ') << c << '\n';
    cout << string(w, c) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to prompt the user for the number of rows and columns. Then, using nested loops, display a rectangle of stars based on the user input.